# Increasing the performance

Tags: java, android

I was implementing an android FFT guitar tuner. Here, I have 2 text views, 1 for displaying the frequency of the sound coming from the mic port and the other 1 for displaying the pitch notation. To match with the frequency, I wrote an if condition which is having about 35 if else if conditions consisting of 150 lines (approximately). Now, when a sound is heard, the value is updated in the frequency text view, but the note pitch text view is getting late to updated since there are so many conditions to be checked before updating the text view, so when the conditions are checked, again the frequency text view may have changed and got itself updated. What can I do to get rid of this problem? The final output is not efficient..Please help me with this...

```
if(frequency >= 62 && frequency <= 65)
{
   note.setText("C");
}
else if(frequency >= 70 && frequency <= 74)
{
  note.setText("C#");
}
else if(frequency >= 77 && frequency <= 81)
{
  note.setText("D");
}
else
{
  note.setText("Frequency is out of range");
}
```

Comment: If you want cleaner code, consider a `switch` statement instead...

Comment: Are you sure that it's the complexity of the if-statement that's causing the slowness? Have you timed how long it's taking for all the conditions to execute? If you haven't, do that before you continue. You can waste a lot of time trying to optimize pieces of code that aren't actually causing the performance problems you're seeing. I say this from experience :)

Comment: Is the switch statement faster than if condition? and I haven't tried to check the time for execution. But since the frequency changes in every second (maybe millisecond), I thought that the no:of if conditions might affect on producing the output as well...

Comment: maybe u need a design change. Drop so many conditions and organize it in groups so that it can selective choose the right condition rather than going through a brute force method. And you could use a timer to check how long its taking to complete the selection task. Could help more if you explained what all the ifs were about

Comment: My code looks like this...

if(frequency == 60)
{
   note.setText("A");
}
else if(frequency == 62)
{
    note.setText("B");
}

So apparently there are approximately 35 conditions having about 150 lines of coding..

Comment: It would help greatly if you could add a piece of those 35 conditions to your question (not into a comment please, it's too cramped).

Comment: If all your conditions are like `if (frequence == X) note.setText("Y")`, then populate a `Map<Integer, String> frequenciesToNotes` with your 35 conditions and replace your 150 lines by `note.setText(frequenciesToNotes.get(frequency))`.

Comment: I updated my 1st post with sample if conditions...The thing is, actually I had to take a range of frequencies since the output is not much accurate...

Comment: @SahanDeSilva With the exclusive range check, the hash look up will still result in minimal checks. Even with that said, this is very unlikely to be your actual performance problem. The problem may be that it's updating too frequently causing the Event Thread to be queued with updates constantly, thus always behind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My answer has following assumption:

- Assuming your bottle-neck is the IF-ELSE

According to Pitch to Frequency mappings, it can be divided into 8 groups.
http://peabody.sapp.org/class/st2/lab/notehz/

**Step 1:**
You may consider 2 level IF-ELSE, which the first level is to determine the group, and second level is to determine the individual pitch note. To reduce the potential amount of IF_ELSE executed.

Example:

```
 if(frequency <= 31) {
   // Group 1
 } else if (frequency <= 62) {
   // Group 2
 } else if (frequency <= 124) {
   // Group 3
   if(frequency >= 62 && frequency <= 65)
   {
       note.setText("C");
   }
   else if(frequency >= 70 && frequency <= 74)
   {
       note.setText("C#");
   }
   else if(frequency >= 77 && frequency <= 81)
   {
       note.setText("D");
   }
 } etc etc
```

**Step 2:** You can make a HashMap for each group. Improving the second level searching.

Let says Group 3 has a HashMap like this:

```
 { 62, "C" }
 { 63, "C" }
 { 64, "C" }
 { 65, "C" }
 { 70, "C#" }
 { 71, "C#" }
 { 72, "C#" }
 { 73, "C#" }
 { 74, "C#" }
```

You code will look similar to this:

```
 Map<Integer,String> mapGroupThree = new HashMap<Integer,String>();
 String result = "";

 if(frequency <= 31) {
   // Group 1
   result = mapGroupOne.get(frequency);
 } else if (frequency <= 62) {
   // Group 2
   result = mapGroupTwo.get(frequency);
 } else if (frequency <= 124) {
   // Group 3
   result = mapGroupThree.get(frequency);
 } etc etc

 textView1.setText(result==null?"Out of Range":result);
```

So finally, you will have 8 IF-ELSE, and each contain 1 map searching.

==================================================================================

Another thing that you can try:

Try to supply frequency in a sampling of 500ms (Or some reasonable value) instead of real time input.
This is to prevent the congestion in UI thread's update.

==================================================================================

Again, I am not a music guy. It is all base on programming perspective. Not sure if it is helpful for you.

Comment: Will hashmap usage reduce the execution time? I mean, will it produce a better performance?

Comment: There are lots of discussion about this. E.g. [This](http://www.znetdevelopment.com/blogs/2010/12/17/java-performance-map-vs-ifelse/)  But again, i think the performance issue in your case is not related to this pieces of code. My answer might help a little but not much.

Comment: You can try to supply your frequency by sampling rate of some 500ms. That will be UI enough time to Update the screen.

Comment: Can you please enhance your answer a little bit more with a sample code? How should I supply the frequency with a rate of 500 ms?

Comment: I can't unless I know how you get your frequency.

Comment: I use a fast Fourier transform class to obtain the frequency.. This is the link which I used as it is to retrieve the frequency..

http://code.google.com/p/android-guitar-tuner/source/browse/?r=2#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fsrc%2Fcom%2Fexample%2FGuitarTuner